# Show Strunk & White before Copy Editor in badge progress popup

Tags: feature-request, badges, popups

The title is pretty self explanatory but I think it would be nice to have the Strunk & White appear before the Copy Editor inside of the Badge Progress popup if you haven't yet made Strunk & White.

This would fit with the current `reviewer -> steward`, `strunk & white -> copy editor`, which is the expected behavior.

[image: Current Popup]

Comment: And also probably the "**Civic Duty**" badge for votes.

Comment: Seems like the same issue. Only difference is mine is a request to change it, while the other is a general question.